# Prove if for a Linear Transformation $T : V \rightarrow V$ over $\mathbb C $ $<v, T(v)> = 0 $ for all $ v \in V$ then $ T(v) = 0 $ for all $ v \in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

Prove that if for a Linear Transformation  $T: V \rightarrow V$ over $\mathbb C $ $\langle v, T(v)\rangle = 0$ for all $ v \in V$ then $ T(v) = 0 $ for all $ v \in V$

Since $ T(v) $ is also in $ \mathbb C$ I checked the linear property of two complex numbers to equal zero.

so $(a + bi)(t + si)  = 0$ would mean that $asi = -bti$ and $at = bs$
so $ -t^2 = s^2 $ 
Where t and s are the coefficients of one of the elements in $T(v)$ so the only number that equals it's negative is 0.

Hi all. This was a homework assignment and I've come up with an alternative proof (that is probably wrong) to the official (which is simple and I understand, but it's completely different), if it is indeed wrong could someone hint where I'm going in the wrong direction with my thinking?

Comment: It may seem something is missing on your question title. Also it could help if you post the question in the body too

Comment: Hi @AleTolcachier thanks. Not missing T(v) not F(v) I had a small typo, but this is the whole question, albeit translated from german. I added it to the body too. thank you.

Comment: Did you mean <v,T(v)>=0?

Comment: Hi @AleTolcachier no, =0. It meant the inner/scalar product of v and the Transformation of v, sorry if this was unclear

Comment: And what is the hypothesis on that inner product? As it is stated, there is no hypothesis

Comment: @AleTolcachier apologies, you mean what type of inner product it is? It doesn't say per se, but it's the standard scalar product.

Comment: You say "<v,T(v)> for all $v\in V$" but you don't specify any property of <v, T(v)>

Comment: @AleTolcachier Oh dear! thank you! Yes, I missed = 0. remidied. So sorry!

Comment: Your proof assumes that $T(v) \in \Bbb C$, which is not true.  If $T:V \to V$, then $T(v) \in V$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you. I don't quite understand though. The question says V over $ \mathbb C $ why does that not mean that T(v) is in $ \mathbb C $ also? Sorry for being slow

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for. When we say that $T:V \to V$ is a linear transformation "over $\Bbb C$", we mean that 
$$
T(\alpha v + \beta w) = \alpha T(v) + \beta T(w)
$$
for any **complex** numbers $\alpha,\beta$. So for instance, the conjugation map $a + bi \mapsto a - bi$ is a map from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$ that is "linear over $\Bbb R$" but not "linear over $\Bbb C$".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you. I kind of get it. Does it mean that the scalar multiplication and addition are linear with complex numbers being the scalars? in your example over C would mean $\alpha, \beta $ are $\in $ $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the scalar multiplication and addition are linear"

Comment: The T(av + bw) = aT(v) + bT(w) is the closed under addition and scalar multiplication for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: there has been some confusion over the terminology. $T$ is "linear over $\Bbb C$" does not mean that the output of $T$ is linear. Rather, when we say that $T:V \to V$ is a linear transformation "over $\Bbb C$", we mean that 
$$
T(\alpha v + \beta w) = \alpha T(v) + \beta T(w)
$$
for any **complex** numbers $\alpha,\beta$. So for instance, the conjugation map $a + bi \mapsto a - bi$ is a map from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$ that is "linear over $\Bbb R$" but not "linear over $\Bbb C$".